# Consequence of Nakayama's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $M$. Let $A$ be a finitely generated $R$-module, and $x_1, ..., x_n$ be a minimal generating subset of $A$. I would like to prove that $x_1 + MA, ... , x_n + MA$ is a basis of $A/MA$ over $R/M$.

The book I am using gives a hint to use Nakayama's Lemma, and I used it to show that $x_1 + MA, ... , x_n + MA$ spans $A / MA$. But how do show that $x_1 + MA, ... , x_n + MA$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R/M$ is a field, if they were dependent, one would be a combination of the others, contradicting the minimality of the generating set.

To clarify the argument we have

$$x_1=r_2x_2+\cdots +r_nx_n+m_1x_1+\cdots +m_nx_n$$ which gives
$$(1-m_1)x_1=r_2x_2+\cdots +r_nx_n+m_2x_2+\cdots +m_nx_n$$ and $1-m_1$ is invertible as $M$ is maximal.

Comment: Why is the fact that $R/M$ is a field relevant? Wouldn't we obtain the same contradiction even if $R/M$ weren't a field?

Comment: But then the coefficients might not be invertible, how would you get $x_1=r_2x_2+\cdots$ ?

Comment: But maybe we just have that some linear combination of the $x_i + MA$ is in $MA$, and hence zero in the quotient but not necessarily $0$ in $A$? Then this wouldn't contradict minimality.

Comment: I think that an alternative approach might be to use the fact that $M$ is maximal and hence prime, which implies that $\sum r_i x_i \in MA$ iff $r_i \in M$ for all $i$.

Comment: Yes, this latter suggestion is a good one. I have edited with a different ending, not sure what the most elegant proof is though.

Comment: It is $\textbf{not}$ true that $\sum r_i x_i \in MA$ iff $r_i \in M$ for all $i$. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3874626/if-m-langle-m-1-dots-m-n-rangle-is-a-finitely-generated-r-module-and-p?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is missing some steps, so I'm going to elaborate:

---

Suppose $x_1, \dots, x_n$ is a minimal generating set for $A$. Then the images $x_1 +MA, \dots, x_n+MA$ generate $A/MA$ over the field $R/M$. We want to show that $x_1 +MA, \dots, x_n+MA$ is a basis for $A/MA$ over $R/M$ and so all that is left to show is that they are linearly independent.

Arguing by contraposition, suppose $x_1 +MA, \dots, x_n+MA$ are linearly dependent. Then we can write
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 +MA &= (r_2+M)(x_2 + MA) + \cdots + (r_n+M)(x_n +MA)\\
&=(r_2x_2 +MA) + \cdots + (r_nx_n + MA)\\
&=(r_2x_2 + \cdots + r_nx_n)+MA.
\end{align}$$
Therefore, $x_1-(r_2x_2 + \cdots + r_nx_n) \in MA$ and since $x_1, \dots, x_n$ generates $A$ we can write $$x_1-(r_2x_2 + \cdots + r_nx_n) = m_1x_1 + \cdots +m_nx_n$$ where $m_i \in M$. So,
$$(1-m_1)x_1 = (r_2+m_2)x_2 + \cdots + (r_n+m_n)x_n$$
and since $m_1 \in M$, then $1-m_1 \notin M$ hence $1-m_1$ is a unit. So, we can write
$$x_1 = s_2 x_2 + \cdots s_nx_n$$
where $s_i = (1-m_1)(r_i+m_i)$. So, $x_1, \dots, x_n$ is not minimal.

By the contrapositive, if $x_1, \dots, x_n$ is a minimal generating set for $M$, then $x_1 +MA, \dots, x_n+MA$ are linearly independent.