# If $M=\langle m_1, \dots, m_n\rangle$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and $P \subset R$ is prime, then $\sum r_i m_i \in PM$ iff each $r_i \in P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> If $M=\langle m_1, \dots, m_n\rangle$ is a finitely generated
> $R$-module and $P \subset R$ is prime, then $\sum r_i m_i \in PM$ if
> and only if each $r_i \in P$?

A comment in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731658/consequence-of-nakayamas-lemma?rq=1) suggested the statement above, but I do not see this.

One direction is trivial.

How can we show that if $r_1 m_1 + \cdots + r_n m_n \in PM$ then each $r_i \in P$.

Is this statement even true?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=\mathbb Z, M=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ and $P=(0)$. We have $6\cdot1=0\in PM$, but $6\notin P$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a similar statement that may be true that the comment in that post was probably referring to?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know any such statement to be honest:-(